# Last element of y-axis and x-axis is not shown in surface plot

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, surface

I have a data frame uploaded as a R object in the drive here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12mCnKYzzj8-CBPK7cS6pRBJwTpFKkti8/view?usp=sharing (It was hard to replicate the data and wanted to use the same data to find the problem)
I did a multilayer surface plot but the last element of y-axis, which is 30, is not showing. Also, in x-axis, the last index is 1729, though there are 1764 rows. I can not figure out why this is happening, since the dimension of my axes are the same and there is no error when plotting. Here is the code:

```
library("plotly")
# the real values
z <- as.matrix(forc.forw.varx.30l.JPM[,1:5])
# maturities
rept <- cbind(rep(5,times=1764),rep(10,times=1764),rep(20,times=1764),
              rep(25,times=1764),rep(30,times=1764))
y <- rept
# index (for date)
x <- seq(1,nrow(forc.forw.varx.30l.JPM),1)
x <- cbind(x,x,x,x,x)

fig <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)
# red pink
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z, x=~x, y=~y, opacity=0.75, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(255,107,184)","rgb(128,0,64)")))
# second layer # blue
z1 <- as.matrix(forc.forw.varx.30l.JPM[,6:10])
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z1, x=~x, y=~y, opacity=0.75, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(107,184,255)","rgb(0,90,124)")))
fig
```

Any help would be appreciated!